# How to insert a line break with no indent in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

This is the code I'm trying :

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\chapter*{\emph{Chapter two}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\setlength\parindent{24pt}Chapter two\\ Explanations on Chapter two}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

The problem with `\\` is that the new line is indented, I tried `\linebreak`, but it wont take it

Comment: why have you `\setlength\parindent{24pt}` there? there never needs to be any formatting commands in that argument, the whole point of the previous `{chapter}` argument is that that specifies whatver format you want for chapter level entries.

Comment: When I asked how to add a title for `\chapter*{}` in toc someone gave me that line. (it's usually why I have strange code sometimes and you ask me why it's there). I will delete it and see if it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using package `tocbasic` and declaring a new tocentry:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=0,
  beforeskip=1em plus 1pt,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt,
  linefill=\hfill,
  entryformat=\textbf,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,
]{tocline}{bchap}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}

\chapter*{\emph{Chapter two}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{bchap}{Chapter two\\Explanations on Chapter two}

\chapter{Chapter three}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If there should be dots between the chapter entries and the page numbers, you can use

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=0,
  beforeskip=1em plus 1pt,
  indent=0pt,
  numwidth=0pt,
  entryformat=\textbf,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,
]{tocline}{bchap}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  pagenumberformat=\textbf
]{tocline}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}

\chapter*{\emph{Chapter two}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{bchap}{Chapter two\\Explanations on Chapter two}

\chapter{Chapter three}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: how can I add dots to the toc in this case ?

Comment: @alfred See my updated answer.

Comment: For some reason in my document where there are 13 chapters, the last `\chapter*{}` is added at the end below the frame instead of creating a new page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{5}% Add dots for \chapters

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter one}

\chapter*{\emph{Chapter two}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
  Chapter two \\ \protect\hspace*{-\cftchapnumwidth}Explanations on Chapter two}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution also works fine.